# How to detect IE custom Toolbar is installed or not?

Tags: javascript, c++, visual-c++, dom-events

I have developed a toolbar (COM) for IE. One of my server application should identify whether the toolbar is installed in client system or not. If it's not installed on the client system the server application should prompt the user to user to install the toolbar.

How can I check whether the toolbar is installed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your toolbar can change the DOM, and Javascript can check this. No change, no toolbar.

Comment: @ MSalters Thanks for the suggestion. Do we have any other option instead of changing the DOM?